# Proof of the relation between Kendall's Tau and Pearson's Rho for the Gaussian Copula

Tags: copula, kendall-tau

I know in the case of the bivariate normal distribution Kendall's Tau is given by
$$
\tau=\frac{2}{\pi}\arcsin({\rho})
$$
where $\rho$ is Pearson's correlation. Can someone given a derivation of this result or provide a reference?

Comment: Its name is GREINER's Equality and can see its proof in https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2830471.

Comment: Check https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3058888/321264. Can also be answered using https://math.stackexchange.com/q/255368/321264.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is proven as Theorem 3.1 in [Fang, Fang, & Kotz, *The Meta-elliptical Distributions with Given Marginals* Journal of Multivariate Analysis, Elsevier, 2002, 82, 1–16](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0047259X01920172/1-s2.0-S0047259X01920172-main.pdf?_tid=d066cbf2-aa60-11e4-9e3b-00000aacb361&acdnat=1422829532_8dce87374dd78c31a79b52885ecfcd25) but that relies on Theorem 2.22 in [K. T. Fang, Kotz, and Ng, "Symmetric Multivariate and Related Distribution,"
Chapman & Hall, London, 1990.] (to which I do not have access).